# Using DataMapper ORM and Codeigniter to select join table value in a many to many relationship

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

I have this table structure:

| users | --- has many > --- | preferences_users | --- < has many --- | preferences |

A preference could be something like "first name" or "surname" but the value for these preferences are stored in the joining table.

I am using Codeigniter and Datamapper ORM to get relational tables into objects, however I am not sure how to get this value in the joining table.

I am doing this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->where('unique_url', $url)->get();
$user->preferences->get_iterated();
```

My relationships are set up so that they both have `$has_many = array('tablename');` and I am able to get the values from each table.

HOwever I want to be able to get a table column value from the joining table, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [in the documentation](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#include_join_fields):

> #### `$object->include_join_fields()`
>
> There are no options for this method. Set it right before adding a
>   relationship. You can either use it before a
>   `{$query}_related_{$model}`, or before calling `get()` on a related item.
>   All fields on the table that are not part of the relationship are
>   included, and are prepended with `"join_"`.
>
> This method may return unexpected results or throw errors with deep
>   relationships.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> // Create User $u = new User(); $u->get_by_id($userid);
>
> // get all alarms for this user, and include the extra 'wasfired'
> field $u->alarm->include_join_fields()->get();
>
> foreach($u->alarm as $alarm) {
>     if($alarm->join_wasfired) {
>         echo("{$alarm->name} was fired\n");
>     } else {
>         echo("{$alarm->name} was NOT fired\n");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> See [Working with Join Fields](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/joinfields.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$Object->joinedObject->include_join_fields()->get();
```

Then to get the join field:

```
$Object->{join}_count;
```

Be aware to add `join_ before field (count) name` as referenced in the documentation.

Thanks.